# Two cron schedules on the same job, but only one is firing

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I use the Quartz scheduler (3.0.7) to schedule several background jobs for our company. I now need a job to be triggered by two separate triggers, but somehow, the job is only executed for one of the two triggers. I use a maximum of two cron expressions from the config file, which have the following values:

```
<!-- monthly, on the 1st day of the month, 10 minutes after midnight -->
<add key="CirculatingCouponsReportSchedule1" value="0 0/10 * ? * * *" />

<!-- weekly, on Mondays, 15 minutes after midnight -->
<add key="CirculatingCouponsReportSchedule2" value="0 1/3 * ? * * *" />
```

The following code is a snippet from my application code. It logs: `...'s job is successfully scheduled for 2 cron schedules`, but only the schedule that triggers once per 10 minutes, is actually executed.

```
                var crons = new List<string>();

            if (CronExpression.IsValidExpression(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Schedule1"]))
            {
                crons.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Schedule1"]);
            }

            if (CronExpression.IsValidExpression(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Schedule2"]))
            {
                crons.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Schedule2"]);
            }

            if (crons.Any())
            {
                var job = new JobDetailImpl("MyJob", typeof(MyReportJob));
                var i = 0;

                crons.ForEach(c =>
                {
                    i++;

                    var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                        .WithIdentity($"MyReportTrigger{i}", "ReportJobs")
                        .WithCronSchedule(c)
                        .Build();

                    scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
                });

                Logger.Log($"{nameof(SendMyReportTask)}'s job is successfully scheduled for {crons.Count} cron schedules.", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.Log($"{nameof(SendMyReportTask)}'s job not scheduled. No valid cron expression found.", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);
            }
```

Does anybody have a clue what the problem is? The first thing I have tried, is making the identities unique by adding a counter, but that doesn't help.

Comment: Have you tried triggering two different _instances_ of the job? I am really not sure but I think I remember that you need to either tell Quartz the job can be executed in parallel or trigger separate instances. But I'd have to recheck. Haven't used it in a while.

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution indeed. I have now moved the instantiation of the job to the loop and added `{i}` to its name, just to be sure, and now it works alright. If you add your comment as a reply, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Please *don't* edit the title to say solved or edit an answer into your question. You apparently already know the right way to indicate that your question is answered - accepting an answer. If you're impatient for Fildor to answer, you can always self answer. If Fildor later does turn their comment into an answer, you can change which answer you accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested: As far as I remember, Jobs can't just be started in parallel as default.

There should be a configuration to enable this, but the job must comply to some rules then (afaik).

Another possibility is to *register a separate instance of the job for each of the triggers*.